# How to have jquery add variables as text to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a method that automatically adds new entries to a web page. Instead the method keeps printing [object Object] on the screen:

```js
class entry{
    constructor(entryTitle, entryContent){
        this.entryTitle = entryTitle; 
        this.entryContent = entryContent;
    }
    createEntry(){
        $('main').append('<section id="sv"></section>');
        $('#sv').append('<h1>' + $(this.entryTitle) + '</h1>');
        $('#sv').append('<p>' + $(this.entryContent) + '<p>');
    }
}

let testEntry = new entry('Test', 'test, test, test');
testEntry.createEntry();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The main problem of your code** is that you are wrapping your text in jQuery: `$(this.entryTitle)` creates a jQuery object, that's why you're seeing `[object Object]`.

The other problem is that in your constructor you have a case deviation between the internal property and the parameter, and also you're not using the second parameter:

```
constructor(entryTitle, entrycontent) {
  this.entryTitle = entryTitle;
  this.entryContent 
}
```

This should be

```
constructor(entryTitle, entryContent) {
  this.entryTitle = entryTitle;
  this.entryContent = entryContent;
}
```

```js
class entry {
  constructor(entryTitle, entryContent) {
    this.entryTitle = entryTitle;
    this.entryContent = entryContent;
  }
  createEntry() {
    let self = this;
    $('main').append('<section id="sv"></section>');
    $('#sv').append([`<h1>${self.entryTitle}</h1>`, `<p>${self.entryContent}<p>`]);
  }
}
let testEntry = new entry('Test', 'test, test, test');
testEntry.createEntry();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```js
class Entry{
    constructor(entryTitle, entrycontent){
        this.entryTitle = entryTitle; 
        this.entryContent = entrycontent;
    }
    createEntry(){
        $('main').append('<section id="sv"></section>');
        $('#sv').append('<h1>' + this.entryTitle + '</h1>');
        $('#sv').append('<p>' + this.entryContent + '<p>');
    }
}

let testEntry = new Entry('Test', 'test, test, test');
testEntry.createEntry();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the create entry function you are using jquery to find the element from the class :

```
   $('#sv').append('<h1>' + $(this.entryTitle) + '</h1>');
```

should be

```
    $('#sv').append('<h1>' + (this.entryTitle) + '</h1>');
```